# Iterating over multiple arrays in Pug

Tags: arrays, node.js, express, iteration, pug

I'm making an image gallery app with Node and Express. I'm using Pug as my template engine. I have separate folders for full size, images as well as thumbnails. Essentially what I want is to render only the thumbnails and make that thumbnail a link to that image.

I'm passing an object with two arrays from the route, and it outputs this to the console:

```
    { link:
   [ '/images/20170902_164510.jpg',
     '/images/IMG-20170903-WA0002.jpg',
     '/images/IMG-20170903-WA0003.jpg',
     '/images/IMG-20170903-WA0004.jpg' ],
  thumb:
   [ '/thumbnails/20170902_164510.jpg',
     '/thumbnails/IMG-20170903-WA0002.jpg',
     '/thumbnails/IMG-20170903-WA0003.jpg',
     '/thumbnails/IMG-20170903-WA0004.jpg' ] }
```

I have my Pug template as follows

```
 each image in images
            a(href=image.link, data-toggle='lightbox')
                img(src=image.thumb)
```

This does not output anything in to the page.

It work if I do this instead

```
 each image in images.thumb
            a(href=image, data-toggle='lightbox')
                img(src=image)
```

But only for the array of thumbnails. So how can I access both of the arrays the appropriate way that I can separate links and thumbnails?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I actually managed to get it to work.

I have my loop as follows

```
each image, i in images.thumb
            a(href=images.link[i], data-toggle='lightbox')
                img(src=image)
```

This does exactly what I wanted. Hopefully this will be helpful to someone in the future!